# Can we have a field implementing two or more interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Would it possible to create a class like this...

```
public class Container implements Serializable {
  private final (Map<Object,Object> & Serializable) map;
  public Container( (Map<Object,Object> & Serializable) map) {
    super();
    this.map = map;
  }
  ....
}
```

Basically, we don't want to bind the map implementation to any class and make sure the implementation implements both Map and Serializable interface.

Many thanks for any idea and help.

Comment: Note that the fact the `Map` implements `Serializable` doesn't mean that the map is serializable - you need all the keys and values to be serializable too (with a little "s" - simply implementing `Serializable` is not enough to guarantee serializability either).

Comment: Would it be possible for not introducing a new Type Parameter in the class? I don't want to make the implementation specific type affecting the Container's type...  @Cootri

Answer (score 2):

You can define a generic type parameter having the required type bounds :

```
class Container<E extends Map<Object,Object> & Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private final E map;

    public Container (E map) 
    {
        super();
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, what if we don't want a default constructor? I tried followings, but seems not working well...

`
    class Container<E extends Map<Object,Object> & Serializable> implements Serializable {

         private final E map;

         public Container (E map) {
            super();
            this.map = map;
         }

         public Container() {
             this(new HashMap<Object,Object>());
         }
    }`